# Can not figure out the JDBC error in IntelliJ

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am learnin JDBC at the moment with IntelliJ and MySQL.
Here is the code that I learned from Telusko on Youtube:

```
package com.company;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customers";
        String uname = "root";
        String pass = "791005596";
        String query = "SELECT * FROM customers.registration\n" +
                "where password like '%123'";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        String userData = "";
        while (rs.next()) {
            userData = rs.getInt("ID") + rs.getString(2);
            System.out.println(userData);

            st.close();
            con.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I already added connector in the library, as I run it on IntelliJ,
it comes in this way:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=1821:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Jocelyn Huang\IdeaProjects\FSD\out\production\FSD;C:\Users\Jocelyn Huang\IdeaProjects\FSD\lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar" com.company.Main
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
231245mamamoo123
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:445)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:1726)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:22)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea what is going on here, for the first line, 
 I try to delete this one :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

And  run again,

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=2687:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Jocelyn Huang\IdeaProjects\FSD\out\production\FSD;C:\Users\Jocelyn Huang\IdeaProjects\FSD\lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar" com.company.Main
231245mamamoo123
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:445)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:1726)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:22)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could someone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could try `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")`? Loading the class that your error message gives you.

Comment: The code you learned is very bad quality. I strongly suggest you find a **non-video** tutorial from a reliable source, so you don't accidentally learn how to write bad code. Seems like this "Telusko" person has written a lot of tutorials for severa languages, meaning he's probably an expert in none of them. I would not try to learn from those videos.

Comment: @marstran That is a warning, the error is _java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed_, and that happens because the OP closes the statement and connection inside the loop over the result set.

Comment: Thank you you Mark, though still cannot understand your explanation, I will try to learn JAVA in a systematic way, hopefully can cathch up later.

Comment: Thanks for your information Kayaman,  and I will take yur advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message to the driver is only a warning, the actual error which causes the exception is the reading of the data.

You close the connection and the statement before all data was read. 
This means that the `ResultSet` can no longer be read when the while loop is processed again.

You must close the connection and the statement after the loop.

```
String userData = "";
while (rs.next()) {
    userData = rs.getInt("ID") + rs.getString(2);
    System.out.println(userData);
}

st.close();
con.close();
```

Comment: It successfully went through now, really appreciated for your help tgallei.